# Flutter: use flutter 2 without migrating into null safety

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use flutter sdk version 2. So after set

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

on package’s pubspec.yaml file, I am ready to use stable version.Before running application I need to run :

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

After running I got alot of error like :

```
The parameter 'restClient' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
```

a few of my libraries that is used before in my project, not migrated to null safety yet So for now I am not ready to migrate my project into null safety.

I want to now Is it a way to use flutter 2 without migrating into null safety ?

Comment: environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'
Still you can use the new API of Flutter 2 
Because above line says Min SDK of Flutter is greater then 2.7.0 and Less then 3.0.0 and 2.12.0 is in between. And you no need to migrate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I'm currently working on a project migrated to Flutter 2 with unsound null safety, simply update your `pubspec.yml` as follow:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: Mean , I can use stable version of flutter web? @GuillaumeRoux

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to now Is it a way to use flutter 2 without migrating into null safety ?

Yes, you can! actually, you can keep your legacy packages that don't support null safety too! But there is a condition you can keep your legacy packages while using flutter 2 without migrating into null safety and walk through package migration hell as long as your base package like intl & flutter_localizations for package localization is compatible. But keep in mind that you need to keep your packages compatible with flutter 2

or you can just run this command

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: Then, What can I do for these errors https://pasteboard.co/JSHmYq6.png  @dwikurniantom

Comment: clear your pubspec.lock, and run flutter pub get

Comment: Then sdk must be <2.12.0? for example `>=2.7.0`? @dwikurniantom

Comment: iam using sdk: ">=2.10.4 <3.0.0", but it's all depends on your dependency (plugins & packages)